# How to read input (a number) and terminate when the user enters '0' at the end of the number

Tags: c++

Tried looking around on stack overflow before publishing this question, but didn't find much help. Basically I am trying to create a function that will read users input to an integer value, but I want the program to stop reading input once 0 is entered. I've tried testing some things but they're not working.

Example of input could look like:

Input: 17520
Read: 1752

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int entry;

    cout << "Enter a positive integer (0 to stop): ";
        do {
        cin.get(entry); // pretty sure cin.get is only applicable for characters?
        } while (cin.get(entry != 48)); // trying to detect when zero is inputted via
                                        // ascii value

}
```

I imagine there is also a way where I don't have to use a for loop and where my value isn't an array, if someone could elaborate on this as well that would be epic. :)

Comment: Why are you creating an array of 100 integers if you want to read characters? Why are there two calls to `get` in your loop? Why are you comparing an integer to the *digit* "0"? It's hard to make sense of what you think this code does.

Comment: You may need to use an Operating Systems function that returns a character.  Most C++ console I/O is buffered.  The User types characters until the Enter key is pressed.  The C++ input library then returns character(s) out of this buffer.  Your mileage may differ.

Comment: BTW, `cin.get` is usually for characters.  If you insist on inputting characters, you'll have build your own integers.  Personally, I have better things to do with my time; which is why I use items in the C++ standard language whenever possible.

Comment: According to your definition, how would I enter the number 10 (ten, decimal)?  The first encounter of the *character* `'0'` would indicate the end of a number, so a 0 cannot be any digit in the number.  This is why you'll need a different separator to indicate the end of a number.  Space or tabs or anything that is not a digit is usually a valid numeric terminator (the period or comma may also be part of a number).

Comment: @Thomas Matthews 0 is applicable for me because the function will be used with another function that utilizes prime numbers. being that there are no even prime numbers, besides two, numbers like 10, 20, 30 and so on are not necessary and therefore don't matter to me.

Comment: Here's an excellent description of the grammar for building a number from characters:  [grammer for number](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/bnf.html).

Comment: @user486543 If you want to terminate the loop when the user enters a number that ends with `0`, then test if the number is evenly divisible by 10, ie `int number; cin >> number; if (number % 10 == 0) break;`

Answer (score 1):

The preferred container, when the capacity is only known at runtime, is the `std::vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    vector<int> entry;

    cout << "Enter a positive integer (0 to stop): ";
    int number = 0;
    while (cin >> number)
    {
        if (number == 0) break;
        entry.push_back(number);
    }
}
```

The `std::vector` will grow as necessary; no wasting of space.

**Edit 1: Limitations**
If you need to impose a limit or capacity, you could do something like this:

```
cout << "Enter a positive integer (0 to stop): ";
int number = 0;
while (cin >> number)
{
    if (number == 0) break;
    if (entry.size() >= LIMIT) break;
    entry.push_back(number);
}
```

Where LIMIT is some constant you define.

Comment: Certainly there is a method to do so without using vectors?

Comment: What do you have against `std::vector`.

Comment: Well, you could ask the User for the capacity, then dynamically allocate the array.  This is how it was done in the olden days.  Remember, if you dynamically allocate too little, you'll have to dynamically allocate another larger array, switch pointers, and delete the old array (as well as copy the data over).  This is done for you by `std::vector`.